# Elasticsearch query to search with mm-yyyy format on date field

Tags: elasticsearch, date-format

I want to query the elasticsearch like 03-2015 on date field which is in yyyy-dd-mm format.

I tried like this, But it didn't worked.Its not giving any error, it is returning 0 records

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty" -d '{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "deliverydate": {
                        "gte": "03-2015",
                        "lte": "03-2015",
                        "format": "mm-yyyy" 
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

}
'

my sample document is this

```
{
"took": 38,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "33924",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "id": 33924,
                "deliverydate": "2015-03-14",
                "name":"New test order"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
```

}

Can anyone please help me on this. Is this a valid search on elasticsearch data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is not correct (`MM` instead of `mm`), it should be

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty" -d '{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "deliverydate": {
                        "gte": "03-2015",
                        "lte": "04-2015",
                        "format": "MM-yyyy" 
                    }
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}}'
```

Comment: No. this is not working..do we need to give the format of elasticsearch field OR need to give search query format?

Comment: What error do you get? and please show a sample document with the `deliverydate` field.

Comment: This is my sample document. {
    "took": 38,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 10,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "mytype",
                "_id": "33924",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 33924,
                    "deliverydate": "2015-03-14",
                    "name":"New test order"

Comment: I am not getting any error..it is returning 0 records

Comment: Well, if you want to retrieve all records for March 2015, see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you were searching for documents with `deliverydate` being exactly `2015-03-01T00:00:00`